# How to move cursor automatically to next line after writing 30 characters in textarea using as3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to know about to move cursor automatically to next line after writing 30 characters in textarea using as3?

```
tf.wordWrap = true;
tf.text= '';
tf.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,textInputHandler);

function textInputHandler(e:Event=null):void
{
    if (tf.text.length == 29)
    {
        var str:String = tf.text;
        tf.text = str + "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try first to write ur own script, and then show it to us, and we try help

Comment: Please check once the above code.@Legendary

Answer (score 0):

After

```
tf.text = str + "\n\n";
```

add

```
tf.setSelection(tf.text.length, tf.text.length);
```

**UPDATE**

If you add a new line `\n\n` it will add but the caret doesn't move to the new line. Method `setSelection` move the caret to the selected position (in you case — to the end of the text).

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining how adding this command solves the problem.